# Can I unshare my real name on Battle.net?

Tags: battle.net

I have a friend on Battle.net who I've shared my real name with through Real ID. We are both friends in real life, so I was completely fine sharing my real name.

Recently my friend started streaming Overwatch on Twitch, which means anyone viewing his stream can see my real name whenever we play together.

**Is there a way to unshare my Real ID with a friend on Battle.net?**

Comment: This should theoretically be doable by turning off RealID sharing in your B.net account settings.

Comment: @Fluttershy Will that do it for all friends, though?

Comment: @SaintWacko Most likely. It disables RealID entirely, so I'd assume it would stop showing your real name with anyone you shared with previously.

Comment: As previous surmised, it's not possible to disable it on a per person basis.

Comment: If you just want to do that for one single person just delete him from your friend list and re-add him using his battle tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible to disable it for just one person.  However, you can disable it for all people.

There is a catch, though.  Battle.Net / Blizzard may remove any friends who added you via email address.  Personally, I don't think it removed any of my contacts when I did this.

If you still want to do this, in the Blizzard client:

1. Click the Blizzard icon.
2. Click Account Management.
3. On the new page, click the Settings menu then Communication Preferences.
4. Uncheck Enable Real ID.
5. There may be prompts that come up warning you about how Real ID friends may be removed.
6. Click the Submit button.

Having said that, many of Blizzard's games have the option of hiding RealID names in-game, although the streamer would have to do this, not you.

To disable the display of Real ID names in Overwatch:

1. Click Options
2. Click Social
3. Change "Display Real IDs For Friends" to "No".

Answer (score -1):

AFAIK you can disable realID but that's global, I don't think you can do a per-person basis.

May 2016 forum on Blizzard: https://us.battle.net/forums/en/bnet/topic/20743804600